# Clickhouse: split output on select

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

Performing a select on Clickhouse, on a MergeTree table that is loaded from a KafkaEngine table via a Materialized View, a simple select shows output split in groups in the `clickhouse-client`:

```
:) select * from customersVisitors;
SELECT * FROM customersVisitors 

┌────────day─┬─────────createdAt───┬──────────────────_id─┬───────────mSId─┬───────xId──┬─yId─┐
│ 2018-08-17 │ 2018-08-17 11:42:04 │  8761310857292948227 │ DV-1811114459  │ 846817     │ 0   │
│ 2018-08-17 │ 2018-08-17 11:42:04 │ 11444873433837702032 │ DV-2164132903  │ 780066     │ 0   │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────┴─────┘
┌────────day─┬─────────createdAt───┬──────────────────_id─┬───────────────────mSId──┬────────xId─┬─yId─┐
│ 2018-08-17 │ 2018-08-17 10:25:11 │ 14403835623731794748 │ DV-07680633204819271839 │ 307597     │ 0   │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴────────────┴─────┘

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.013 sec.
```

Engine is `ENGINE = MergeTree(day, (mSId, xId, day), 8192)`

Why does the output appear splitted in two groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the output is split when the data came from different blocks, also often it leads to being processed in different threads. If you want to get rid of it, wrap your query in outer select

```
select * from (...)
```

Comment: Or add `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

**[MergeTree Engine](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/)** is designed for faster WRITE and READ operations.

Fater writes are achieved by inserting data in parts and then the data is merged offline into a single part for faster reads.

you can see the data partition the following directory :

```
 ls /var/lib/clickhouse/data/database_name/table_name
```

If you run the following query, you will find this that the data is now available in a single group and also a new partition is available at the above location :

```
optimize table MY_TABLE_NAME
```

Optimize table forces merging of partition, but in usual cases, you can just leave it on Click house .