# Why does ClickHouse client return multiple tables?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm very new to Clickhouse and my first attempts seem to always generate this kind of output for SELECT:

```
:) select * from test

SELECT *
FROM test 

┌─s───┬───i─┐
│ foo │ 123 │
└─────┴─────┘
┌─s───┬───i─┐
│ bar │ 567 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I would expect something like:

```
┌─s───┬───i─┐
│ foo │ 123 │
│ bar │ 567 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Why do I get separate rows ? Is it caused by the table structure ? Here's the structure of the `test` table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    s String,
    i UInt64
) ENGINE = Memory
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/51899472/72178

Answer (score 6):

## Background

ClickHouse has a vectorized query execution engine which means when interpreting queries, it consumes data in batches. The definition of a batch is heavily related to the underlying storage engines. Since you are using the **Memory** engine, it formulates batches per insertion (or split large insertions into separate batches w.r.t the **max_insert_block_size** setting).

## Answer

The reasons that you got separate table rows in the query output are as follows:

- You've inserted two blocks (two **INSERT** statements) into the **test** table, thus scanning from it generates two blocks.
- The query you are using doesn't contain any blocking operators (group by, order by, etc) which merge blocks. So the generated blocks are returned one by one.
- The commandline client prints blocks immediately when receiving them.

Comment: Seems like adding an ORDER BY clause forces the server to collect all results and form a single table result.

Answer (score 4):

By default clickhouse-client uses [PrettyCompact](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#prettycompact) output format:

> PrettyCompact
>
> Differs from Pretty in that the grid is drawn between rows and the
> result is more compact. This format is used by default in the
> command-line client in interactive mode.

If you want to join all output blocks you can use slightly different output format [PrettyCompactMonoBlock](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#prettycompactmonoblock):

> PrettyCompactMonoBlock
>
> Differs from PrettyCompact in that up to 10,000 rows are buffered,
> then output as a single table, not by blocks.